# Jquery Multiselect onblur method

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

How can i call onblur method on jquery mutiselect?
Like in my multiselect i have below values if user select red and green then based on that i need to fetch data from db

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="myID" name="myName">
    <option value="blue">blue</option>
    <option value="red">red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>                
</select>
```

I tried `click` function but that can send only one option value at a time so looking for `onblur` like of function in jquery multiselect or any event that triggers after selecting all the values from multiselect i mean if user click outside multiselect.

thanks in advance.any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `.change()` may be works fine

Comment: @Gautam - is this resolved or should I take a look?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/) method

```
var selectedvals = [];
$('#myID').blur(function() {
    $('#myID > option:selected').each(function(i, selected) {
        selectedvals.push($(selected).val());
    });
})​
```

the `selectedvals` array contains the values from the selected options

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/E6kA6/)

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery 1.7.1

```
$('#myID').on('blur', function(){
    var selected=[];

    $(this).find('option:selected').each(function(i,e){
        selected.push(e.value);
    });
    alert('You selected: ' +selected.join(','));

});​
```

Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/xQsUV/)

Comment: thanks for reply but this is not working in JqueryMultiselect plugin

Comment: OK.  I assume you are using [this](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/).  If so, try to simulate a 'blur' with the following...                 `$('#multiselect-demo + .ui-multiselect').click(function(){$(this).one('mouseout',function(){alert('blur');});})`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for `$('#myID').change()`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#myID").change(function(){
    var selected = $("#myID option:selected").val();
    // Do your stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when you add an onblur event. Like so..

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="myID" name="myName" onblur="getVals(this)">
<option value="blue">blue</option>
<option value="red">red</option>
<option value="green">green</option>
```

```
function getVals(el) {
    var val = $(el).val();
    alert(val);
}
```

If you select like red and green it will return both values seperated by a comma like this - "red,green"

You would just have to parse it and send it to the backend script for processing.